# printing even numbers with lists and brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

When I run the following code for some reason it says that the break is incorrect but works if I delete the break.

Can anyone help me to understand why?

```
composites = []
for i in range(101):
    for j in range(i):
        if (i % j) == 0:
            composites.append(i)
            break
print("Composites: ", *composites)
```

Comment: does anyone know a answer

Comment: for starters when j==0 i%j is undefined and should raise an error

Comment: @MegaBluejay when `j==0` then the inner for loop never executes... so that won't happen.

Comment: The sample code runs with a ZeroDivisionError because of `i % 0`

Comment: @Jon Clements when i==0 the interior loop never executes. j is the counter for the interior loop, so its execution couldn't possibly depend on it

Comment: @boonwj it has an error because of the break (at least that is what it says)

Comment: it gives me `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` this is not because of break

Comment: [me too](https://ibb.co/d6HNkA)

Comment: okay now its saying ZeroDivisionError(at first it said the break was wrong)

Comment: I think what needs to be done is just change the starting value of the second range. Instead of `range(i)` use `range(2, i)`. It worked on my end after this.

Comment: range(1,100) and range(1,j) will work fine, then it start from 1 to end-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample code provided threw a `ZeroDivisionError` instead of a break error. Problem is with the second range as the modulo function cannot be done with 0.

Since composites are non-prime numbers, factors checking should start from 2. Changing the second range function to `range(2, i)` should solve this.

```
composites = []
for i in range(101):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if (i % j) == 0:
            composites.append(i)
            break
print("Composites: ", *composites)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me in python 3.7, range(10) will produce [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] which will give `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`

```
composites = []
   for i in range(1,101):
      for j in range(2,i):
        if (i % j) == 0:
          composites.append(i)
          break
print("Composites: ", *composites)
```

Comment: second range should be (2, i)

Comment: then it is missing 2 from output @MegaBluejay

Comment: or, better yet, (2, math.trunc(math.sqrt(i))

Comment: 2 should not be in the output

Comment: it's prime :)))

Comment: oops sorry it should evens instead of composites